# msxsl:node-set() not recognized

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to pull nodes out of a node set stored in a variable using the msxsl:node-set() function and am not getting anything.  My xml looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Items olditemnumber="100" newitemnumber="200">
    <Item ItemNumber="100" ItemAliasCode="1001" ItemCode="X" />
    <Item ItemNumber="100" ItemAliasCode="1002" ItemCode="X" />
    <Item ItemNumber="200" ItemAliasCode="2001" ItemCode="X" />
    <Item ItemNumber="200" ItemAliasCode="2003" ItemCode="X" />
    <Item ItemNumber="100" ItemAliasCode="1003" ItemCode="P" />
    <Item ItemNumber="100" ItemAliasCode="1004" ItemCode="P" />
    <Item ItemNumber="200" ItemAliasCode="2002" ItemCode="P" />
  </Items>
</Root>
```

In my xslt I try to populate a variable with a subset of the  nodes and then call them using the msxsl:node-set() function.  This doesn't return anything however.
XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:template match="//Root">
   <xsl:variable name="OldItemNumber" select="/Items/@olditemnumber"/>
   <xsl:variable name="NewItemNumber" select="/Items/@newitemnumber"/>
   <xsl:variable name="OldItems">
     <xsl:value-of select="//Item[@ItemNumber = $OldItemNumber]"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="NewItems">
     <xsl:value-of select="//Item[@ItemNumber = $NewItemNumber]"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($OldItems)/Item">
     ...work
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT skips over the for-each loop, though I see in the watch that the the Xpath query grabs the right nodes in assigning the variables.  The watch also tells me that the msxsl:node-set() function is undefined.  Any help would be appreciated.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:template match="//Root">
   <xsl:variable name="OldItemNumber" select="/Items/@olditemnumber"/>
   <xsl:variable name="NewItemNumber" select="/Items/@newitemnumber"/>
   <xsl:variable name="OldItems" select="//Item[@ItemNumber = $OldItemNumber]"/>
   <xsl:variable name="NewItems" select="//Item[@ItemNumber = $NewItemNumber]"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$OldItems">
     ...work
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`msxsl:node-set` is for converting a result tree fragment (a.k.a. RTF) to a node set, which is not needed on your case.

`xsl:value-of` is for creating text nodes, so don't use it for selecting nodes of the input tree that you want to further query/process.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!  I did not realize xsl:value-of could not be used in that manner.